# change the cell reference link according to another cell

Tags: excel

There are excel files every day created on this network location (Source File)  "J:\public\Daily Report\Daily Reports\2016\08 Aug\ModecDaily Report Use\Daily Report 13-08-2016.xlsx".

I want to copy some of these cell contents to another excel file here ( destination file)"J:\public\Daily Report\Daily Reports\2016\08 Aug\OIM Form\Daily Report Summary 13-08-2016.xls".

The new source/destination file will be created with the date changed everyday and this has to be done everyday

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Done as below

Sub Add_Bridge_1()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

```
'add your own file path
fileStr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(fileStr)

'wbk2.Sheets("Bridge 1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Daily Report 99-08-2016.xlsx").Production Rep
wbk2.Sheets("Production Rep").Copy After:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
wbk2.Saved = True
```

End Sub

where i gave the formula on A1

Regards
Ganesan